# Eclipse c, chip family STM32F107RCT6

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, eclipse-luna

I am confused to select chip for my new eclipse project under chip family dropbox. 
There is options

- Low density
- Low density value line
- Medium density
- Medium density value line
- High density
- High density value line 
  Which one I have to select.

Comment: What kind of project is this?

Comment: C project, stm32-discovery

Comment: I strongly suggest that you add that information into your question then...

Comment: Sorry again forget it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Low-density value line devices (LD_VL) are STM32F100xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 16 and 32 Kbytes.
- Medium-density value line devices (MD_VL) are STM32F100xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 64 and 128 Kbytes.
- High-density value line devices (HD_VL) are STM32F100xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 256 and 512 Kbytes.
- Low-density devices (LD) are STM32F101xx, STM32F102xx and STM32F103xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 16 and 32 Kbytes.
- Medium-density devices (MD) are STM32F101xx, STM32F102xx and STM32F103xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 64 and 128 Kbytes.
- High-density devices (HD) are STM32F101xx and STM32F103xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 256 and 512 Kbytes.
- XL-density (XL) devices are STM32F101xx and STM32F103xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 768 Kbytes and 1 Mbyte.
- Connectivity line** (CL) devices are STM32F105xx and STM32F107xx microcontrollers."**
  (rm0041 v3, rm0008 v12)